# Calculating parameter-limit in some infinite double series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, gamma-function

Let $\Gamma(x) := \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} \, \text d t$ denote the (Euler-)Gamma function.

For $0<\alpha<1/2$, I want to calculate the limit $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \alpha\,n\rfloor} \frac{\Gamma(x+\frac{n}{3})\,\Gamma(x+\frac{n+1}{3})\,\Gamma(x+\frac{n+2}{3})}{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(k+x+1)\,\Gamma(n-k+x+1)} $$ or at least find a small upper bound. (According to some computations with python using mpmath the result might well be $0$.)

EDIT: With $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_1+x_2+x_3;\,1/3,1/3,1/3):= \frac{(x_1+x_2+x_3)!}{x_1!\,x_2!\,x_3!\, 3^{x_1+x_2+x_3}}$ the probability mass function of the equiprobable trinomial distribution as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), the problem is equivalent to calculating $$ \lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\x\in\mathbb N}} \sum_{\substack{k_1,k_2\in \mathbb N_0\\k_1 < \alpha(k_1+k_2)}} f(x-1,x+k_1,x+k_2;\, 1/3,1/3,1/3).$$

For any $x\in\mathbb N$, we have $$\sum_{k_1,k_2\in \mathbb N_0} f(x-1,x+k_1,x+k_2;\, 1/3,1/3,1/3)=1.$$

Comment: Fix $k,n$. Is the function $\frac{\Gamma(x+\frac{n}{3})\,\Gamma(x+\frac{n+1}{3})\,\Gamma(x+\frac{n+2}{3})}{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(k+x+1)\,\Gamma(n-k+x+1)}$ monotonic in $x$? If so, I can show the answer is $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21 My computational checks suggest that the function about which your are asking is not always monotonic in $x$. See, for instance, a [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtOEC.png) drawn by MathCad for $n=10$ and $k=3$.

Comment: @mathworker21 For $k=0$ the function is unimodal with the mode increasing with $n$. Hence there is not even an uniform (i.e. independent of $n$) $x_0$ with the function being monotonic for $x>x_0$.

Comment: @metamorphy what was it? im curious. (people with over 10k rep can see deleted answers)

Comment: @mathworker21: well, "hint" - my $S(x)$ is in fact constant (!) equal to $\Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(2/3)$.